# Reference Error: AppsScript Email using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send HTML table in an email with dynamic output in each cell. It pulls data from a Google Sheet powered by AppsScript.

**The problem is:

> ReferenceError: stocks is not defined eval     eval    doGet**

I'm stuck on how to define the value "stocks" on the HTML side.

(PS- I'm trying to do exactly what this tutorial is teaching: https://spreadsheet.dev/send-html-email-from-google-sheets)

HTML:

```html
</tr>     
               <? for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) { ?>
                <tr style="height:66pt">
                    <td style="border-width:0.984375pt 0.984375pt 0.984375pt 2.25pt;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(183,183,183);vertical-align:top;padding:5pt;overflow:hidden">
                        <p dir="ltr" style="line-height:2.0736;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;color:rgb(67,67,67);font-weight:700;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap">Business Group</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-width:0.984375pt;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(183,183,183);vertical-align:top;padding:5pt;overflow:hidden">
                        <p dir="ltr" style="line-height:2.0736;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;color:rgb(67,67,67);font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap">Which of these business groups is affected by this event: </span></p>
                        <p dir="ltr" style="line-height:2.0736;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;color:rgb(67,67,67);font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap">Corporate Systems &amp; Applications, MITS, THPS, or TELUS International?</span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-width:0.984375pt 2.25pt 0.984375pt 0.984375pt;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(183,183,183);vertical-align:top;padding:5pt;overflow:hidden">
                        <p dir="ltr" style="line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap"><?= stocks[i].ROW1 ?><
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <? } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

JS:

```js
function doGet(stockData) {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template2.html");
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  return htmlBody;
}


function getEmailText(stockData) {
  var text = "";
  stockData.forEach(function(stock) {
  });
  return text;
}

function sendEmail() {
  var stockData = getData();
  var htmlBody = doGet(stockData);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "sample@email.com",
    subject: "Stock update",
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  });
}

function getData() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TEST").getRange("TEST").getValues();
  values.shift(); //remove headers
  var stocks = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var stock = {};

    stocks.ROW1 = value[0];
    stocks.ROW2 = value[1];
    stocks.ROW3 = value[2];
    stocks.push(stock);

  })
 // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(stocks))
  return stocks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing:

```
stocks.ROW1 = value[0];
stocks.ROW2 = value[1];
stocks.ROW3 = value[2];
stocks.push(stock);
```

With:

```
stock.ROW1 = value[0];
stock.ROW2 = value[1];
stock.ROW3 = value[2];
stocks.push(stock);
```